# Storing and returning input variable from HTML form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been reading other questions and the suggestions I've tried haven't worked for me. I'm trying to have the user enter a number and have it returned in the form of a JS alert (for now).  Here is my code:

HTML

```
<form id="form">
Enter your guess: <input id="guessbox" type="text" name="userguess">
<input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var guess = document.getElementById("guessbox").value;
alert(guess);
```

I keep getting 'null' for the value of my input box and I want the value I enter to be turned into the variable "guess" upon clicking the submit button. I'm sure I'm just missing something basic here.

Comment: When do you call your js code?

Comment: In the example I posted, I guess I don't... however I've tried writing a function with that JS code and I used onClick="thefunction()" on the submit button. I don't really know what to use other than that, which I apparently used incorrectly.

Comment: you can use `onsubmit=thefunction()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
<form name="form" onSubmit="returnGuess()">
Enter your guess: <input id="guessbox" type="text" name="userguess">
<input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function returnGuess(){
    var guess = document.forms["form"]["userguess"].value;
    alert(guess);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. That solved it. So the document.forms.value method takes the form name and the input name within the form and returns the value of said input. Out of curiosity, what is the significance of closing the text input tag but not the submit button input tag?

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the original code didn't work. `document.getElementById("guessbox")` should be equivalent.

Comment: I think it was onSubmit in the form that I was really missing. I had tried to use onClick on the submit button without success.